# JAVA UnsupportedOperationException (The Security Manager is deprecated) on Windows 10 + OpenJDK

Tags: security, java, web-applications, jvm

I am using OpenJDK on Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\divym>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)

C:\Users\divym>
```

On executing a JAVA web application (*.jnlp), I am getting below exception:

```
[divym][ITW-JAVAWS][WARNING_ALL][Fri Nov 24 18:40:52 IST 2023][net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.logging.FileLog.getHeadlineHeader(FileLog.java:53)] NETX Thread# 2b053c0b, name Output controller consumer daemon writer-based impl.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
    at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:429)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPRuntime.initialize(JNLPRuntime.java:268)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.init(Boot.java:353)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JnlpBoot.run(JnlpBoot.java:58)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:274)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:63)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:214)
```

This application was previously working on my device with Oracle JAVA, after I added a url to Java control panel -> security -> Exception site list.

In IcedTea-Web control panel, I do not see any similar option. I have tried setting Security Level to Low. But this did not help.

[image]

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Use a compatible Java version for the .jnlp file.